# Backtracking lexer for ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, jscript, antlr3, lexer

I'm extending a JavaScript ANTLR grammar that uses the C target to handle JScript's conditional compilation comments, i.e. `/*@cc_on ... @*/`.

These need to be handled separately from normal block comments since `/*@cc_on /* hello */ @*/` results in a single conditional compilation comment that extends until the second end-of-comment marker.

I'm starting from the familiar lexer rule:

```
Comment
  : '/' '*' (options {greedy=false;} : .)* '*' '/' { $channel=HIDDEN; }
  ;
```

and I'm adding a new lexer rule to consume conditional compilation blocks:

```
Comment
  : '/' '*@cc_on' (options {greedy=false;} : .)* '@*' '/' { $channel=HIDDEN; }
  | '/' '*' (options {greedy=false;} : .)* '*' '/' { $channel=HIDDEN; }
  ;
```

When the generated lexer sees the conditional compilation opening `/*@cc_on` but does not find a closing statement `@*/` in the rest of the file, it's supposed to backtrack and use the ordinary block comment rule to consume its input. However, the generated lexer doesn't do that -- it seems that when it sees `/*@cc_cond` it scans the rest of the file for `@*/` and throws an error when it cannot find it instead of backtracking.

Thus, parsing

```
var a = /*@cc_on /* ends here */ 1, b = 2
```

throws instead of succeeding: (error printing code is mine and might be buggy, I believe in this case it should point after the `2`)

```
Lexer Error: <input>(1) : error 1 : Unexpected character, Line: 1, Col: 40, Token Text: <<</*@cc_on /* ends here */ 1, b = 2>>>
Lexer Error location:
var a = /*@cc_on /* ends here */ 1, b = 2
----------------------------------------^

Parser Error: -end of input-(1) : error 3 : , at offset -1 , at <EOF>
 : cannot match to any predicted input...
```

How can I edit my comment rule to get the behavior I need? The grammar already has `backtrack=true`.

Edit:
Adding `options { backtrack=true; k=1; }` to the rule did the trick. Why though? `backtrack` was already enabled for the whole grammar.